# Finding which cell a point belongs to given that the cells are not of the same size

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a map that is divided into unequally sized cells. I want to find out which cell a point belongs to. For a grid where the cells are equally shaped, this is fairly simple. However, how do I solve the problem where the cells are unequal?

Specifically: given a pandas dataframe of cells `d`, with each row of the dataframe containing the index of the cell, the northwest and southeast `x,y` coordinates, and given `px` and `py`, the coordinates of the point we want to investigate, find out which row of the dataframe i.e. which cell the point belongs to.

I tried computing the distance to the center of each cell and assigning the point to the closest center's cell, but that doesn't work for points that are near the boundaries of large cells and close to the center of smaller ones.

Edit 1: A single row in a dataframe looks like:

```
cellID southeastX southeastY northwestX northwestY
```

and I compute `sqrt((px-((southeastX+northwestX)/2))**2+(py-((southeastY+northwestY)/2))**2)` for all rows. Whichever cell index has the lowest distance is the cell I assign it to.

Comment: share how your dataframe looks, your attempt till now.

Comment: Are your cells still square?  It would seem so, since you are only specifying only the two corners, but it isn't clear from your description.

Comment: They are rectangular, not square. I think the only realistic approach is to check whether ``px`` and ``py`` lie in between the X and Y values of each cell, drastically increasing computational time, but I don't think there's a more clever approach.

Comment: checking less than and greater than are much faster than calculating squares and square roots.

Comment: Ah, I see. I should have made my question more specific because I wanted to ask if there was a better way that the one I had.

Comment: The condition I gave below is *the* condition for identifying whether you are in the cell or not.  The optimization problem is how to find the right cell without having to check every single cell in your grid.  I would imagine that a bisection approach would be your best bet here, assuming that your dataframe is ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the cells are rectangular, the condition that a point is inside a particular cell is

```
( northwestX < px < southeastX ) and ( southeastY < py < northeastY )
```

Edit: how to actually write this for a pandas DataFrame.  To make the code a little shorter (and possibly a bit less ambiguous) let us assume that each row in the DataFrame `df` has the corner values `xlo`, `xhi`, `ylo`, and `yhi`.  Then to get the cell that contains the point `x`, `y` you want

```
df[(df['xlo']<x) & (df['xhi']>x) & (df['ylo']<y) & (df['yhi']>y)]
```

DataFrames don't support the `a < x < b` syntax and require `&` instead of `and`

Answer (score 0):

If you have many repeated such search for a fixed set of cells, you can use some variation on [Binary Space Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)

The idea is to build a tree where each node enable to divide the number of remaining possible rectangles by two. This can normally be done using a single test either on X or Y axis. The details will of course depend of your specific distribution of cells. Then when you find a single possible cell, you just check if the point is or isn't inside it.

This method is more complicated than the linear search in accepted answer (because you have to build the search tree) but has O(n) complexity, n being the number of cells.

You could also only partition on a single axis after sorting the data along that axis and rather than a tree use a dichotomic search in an array (can become inefficient or complicated when arrays are overlapping when projected to that axis).

Depending on your actual time constraints and data structures these ideas may or may not be useful.

[not going to provide sample code for now, but maybe later as it's a fun exercise]

Comment: This is more along the lines of the answer I was looking for, but for my particular scenario it seems faster to do it with linear search, even though I have to do it a repeated number of times.

Comment: Rule 0 of optimization : don't. If you already have a good enough algorithm no need to search for a better one. :-)

Comment: Actually my answer doesn't indicate anything about the search process.  : )

Comment: @Malcolm: right, it's just about testing if the point is inside the rectangle. On the other hand you can exclude a point by failing just one of the four inequalities, which is handy for fast filtering. I'm quite sure it can be translated rather directly to a set of pandas filters, which should be both simple and fast.